# Android BottomNavigationView Icon and text label overlap each other in Emulator tablet

Tags: android, kotlin, tablet, bottomnavigationview

I have created layout with help of [sdp Library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) and [ssp Library](https://github.com/intuit/ssp), When testing in Nexus 10 API 24 emulator, BottomNavigationView show icon and text label which overlap each other. It work fine with mobile screen.

BottomNavigationView : android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView,

Bottom navigation height : @dimen/_43sdp equivalent to 56dp in mobile,

Bottom navigation icon size : @dimen/_18sdp,

Bottom navigation text label size : @dimen/_12ssp,

I am unable to understand whats going wrong. Please guide me.

Layout code:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cord_home_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.mainHome.MainNavigationActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        style="@style/BottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_navigation_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemIconSize="@dimen/bottom_navigation_icon_size"
        app:elevation="@dimen/_6sdp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>

    <!--app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Screenshot of tablet screen:

[image: Screenshot Tablet Screen]

Comment: post your layout

Comment: Layout added. @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: In the BottomNavigationView use android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Tryed but it doesn't help

Answer (score 4):

Just increase your bottom navigation view height. It will override default height. Let me know if it's not working because currently, I have done it.

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">86dp</dimen>
```